# Can't add a child group in ReportViewer - Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, reportviewer, report-viewer2010

I am trying to add a child group on a report (RDLC file) and I can't get it to work.  If I right click on the details line of the Tablix it lets me select "Add Group" but then the "Child Group..." option is grayed out.

Please help.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not positive that a 'Child Group' is exactly what you think it is.  In order to add a child group, first add a parent group to the data row.  After you have the parent group set up, if you right click in the new column containing the parent group expression and go to add group, you can now select child group.

so...

1) Add a parent group
2) Right click on the expression cell for the parent column
  2.a) Select 'Add Group'
  2.b) Select 'Child Group'

I believe the mindset behind this is that you can't have a child group that doesn't have a parent.